# Domain Authorization Code & Contact Details

Tags: domains

For a .com gTLD, Who generates the Authorization Code, Registry(Verisign) or relevent registrar(goDaddy)? Is there a provision for us(customer) to generate Authorization Code?

Which parties get access to our domain contact details. if it is privacy protected from registrar level? (via EPP and etc...) does registrar send our contact details to Verisign when we registering the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no provision for us to generate the initial EPP code, however as a customer you can easily change it once the domain has been registered.

I don't have a definitive answer on contact details, but my experience as a domain reseller is that if there is domain privacy, then the registrant never receives official domain emails e.g. transfer approval, and to transfer a domain you need to remove privacy first.  To me this implies that the contact details are embedded with the domains at ICANN level.

But do they have the true contact details?  It is all a bit of a dark art.